# Is it possible to create a custom View Type?

Tags: list-view, custom

I've created some custom XSL and CAML (2007 and 2010 compatible) which is working quite cheerfully in a View on a custom List. However, I need to be able to let users add this form of View to any list they like, as if it was just another View Type (like a calendar or such).

Is there a way to create a custom View Type in order to achieve this? Unfortunately I'll need the features associated with this functionality (custom Create and Modify View pages), so it's unlikely alternative workarounds will be appropriate.

Comment: Very good question Stuart.. I'll see If I can come up with something... not supported oob, that I know.

Comment: @Fox: Thanks. I'm increasingly unsure it's possible at all. The fact that SPViewType is a hard-coded enumeration doesn't bode well, along with the absence of (documented) CustomAction registration, and there's not even a foothold I can find that's targetted enough to let me use more workaroundish methods. If you find similar, feel free to add a "Doesn't seem possible" answer.

Comment: Hi Stuart. The only way I can see, is to edit the View Selector ASPX page and have some code which creates the view for that List if it doesn't exist and then select that view.. Sorry Mate, seems you're stuck with this one..

Comment: @Fox: Thanks for looking anyway. You should put that in an answer so I can mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can see, is to edit the View Selector ASPX page and have some code which creates the view for that List if it doesn't exist and then select that view.. Sorry Mate, seems you're stuck with this one..

Comment: Unfortunately modifying that page isn't an option in our circumstance; I agree there doesn't appear to be an alternative method other than that.